# proc sql statement to sum on values/rows that match a condition

Tags: sql, sas

I have a data table like below:

Table 1:

```
ROWID  PERSONID  YEAR  pidDifference  TIMETOEVENT  DAYSBETVISIT
10      111      2009       .          100            .
110     120      2009        9         10             .
231     120      2009        0         20             10
222     120      2010        0         40             20
221     222      2009       102        10             30
321     222      2009        0         30             20
213     222      2009        0         10             20
432     321      2009        99        10             0
211     432      2009        111       20             10
212     432      2009        0         20             0
```

I want to sum over the `DAYSBETVISIT` column only when the `pidDifference` value is 0 for each `PERSONID`. So I wrote the following proc sql statement.

```
proc sql;
create table table5 as
(
   select rowid, YEAR, PERSONID, pidDifference, TIMETOEVENT, DAYSBETVISIT,
   SUM(CASE WHEN PIDDifference = 0 THEN DaysBetVisit ELSE 0 END)
   from WORK.Table4_1 
   group by PERSONID,TIMETOEVENT, YEAR
);

quit;
```

However, the result I got was not summing the `DAYSBETVISIT` values in rows where `PIDDifference = 0` within the same `PERSONID`. It just output the same value as was present in `DAYSBETVISIT` in that specific row.

Column that I NEED (sumdays) but don't get with above statement (showing the resultant column using above statement as OUT:

```
ROWID  PERSONID   YEAR  pidDifference  TIMETOEVENT  DAYSBETVISIT sumdays  OUT
10      111      2009       .          100            .            0      0
110     120      2009        9         10             .            0      0
231     120      2009        0         20             10           30     10
222     120      2010        0         40             20           30     20
221     222      2009       102        10             30           0      0
321     222      2009        0         30             20           40     20
213     222      2009        0         10             20           40     20
432     321      2009        99        10             0            0      0
211     432      2009        111       20             10           0      0
212     432      2009        0         20             0            0      0
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I am using SAS EG Version 7.15, Base SAS version 9.4.

Comment: why dont u just do: select PERSONID,SUM(CASE WHEN PIDDifference = 0 THEN DaysBetVisit ELSE 0 END) from WORK.Table4_1 group by PERSONID

Comment: Thank you. I need to retain all columns and I still need those records where PIDDifference <>0.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: It gives completely wrong result if I do not put the group by statement.

Comment: You need to remove `TIMETOEVENT` from the GROUP BY clause. If you're grouping on that variable each unique value will remain and I strongly suspect that's not what you want.

Comment: Whether year should be included as well is also something you need to consider.

Comment: Doesn't give correct results with removal of year or timetoevent. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: What columns do you want to use for grouping? Based on your description I thought it was PERSONID ("pidDifference value is 0 for each PERSONID"), your code uses PERSONID & TIMETOEVENT & YEAR and your expected results make sense only when you group by PERSONID & pidDifference

Comment: This data is supposed to be grouped (sorted) by first PersonID then TimeToEvent then Year. This table has a sequence of activity (by TimeToevent and Year)  for each PersonID. Hence, the output table should remain as sorted but also include in a new column the total number (sum) of the Daysbetvisit variable.  Thank you.

Comment: What I meant is why in the 3rd line the expected output is `sumdays = 30` when `PERSONID = 120` has `pidDifference = 9` on the second line? The condition "0 for each PERSONID" is false if you group the data by PERSONID.

Comment: Ok. so the logic for the sumdays is-- SUM the daysbetvisit only when piddifference = 0 for that specific PERSONID and keep the table grouped by personID, TimetoEvent, Year.  Therefore the 3rd record sums 20+10 for PERSONID 120. Makes sense? Thanks for your time. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data it looks like you just need to use two CASE statements. One to define which values to `SUM()` and another to define whether to report the SUM or not.

```
proc sql ;
 select personid, piddifference, daysbetvisit, sumdays
      , case when piddifference = 0
             then sum(case when piddifference=0 then daysbetvisit else 0 end)
        else 0 end as WANT
 from expect
 group by personid
 ;
quit;
```

Results

```
                   pid
PERSONID    Difference  DAYSBETVISIT   sumdays      WANT
--------------------------------------------------------
     111             .             .         0         0
     120             0            10        30        30
     120             0            20        30        30
     120             9             .         0         0
     222             0            20        40        40
     222             0            20        40        40
     222           102            30         0         0
     321            99             0         0         0
     432             0             0         0         0
     432           111            10         0         0
```

Comment: Thanks @TOM. Your solution worked well except that I needed to sort the table again so that the history for each PERSONID remained in order.  That made it a 2 step process. I had already got to getting my result using a 2 step process but was hoping to find a logic that would do everything in 1 step. But thanks for the code because I did not know that I could write it like that. Greatly appreciate it!

Comment: In SQL you must use an ORDER BY clause if you require that the data be in a particular order. Otherwise the query could return the values in whatever order it wants.  I did not add an ORDER BY clause in my example as I did not see any variables in your sample data that could be used to define the order.  Also I wanted to include only the minimal required variables so the example output was clearer.

Comment: Thank you Tom. I gave all the required variables in my example and need them to remain in the output.  I am trying to see how to get this result but have the data already grouped because it does work if I group by PersonID only . But then I need to go through another sorting step to group first by PersonID, then TimeToevent then Year.

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are asking, but perhaps you just need to add `ORDER BY PERSONID ,TIMETOEVENT ,YEAR` to the query?  Obviously include any variables you need, or replace all but the new derived variable with `*` and it will select all of the existing variables.

Comment: Yes, THANKS! I added the order by like this and it worked wonderfully. All done in 1 step.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             FROM work.table   group by PERSONID) ORDER BY PERSONID, TIMETOEVENT, YEAR;
quit;

Answer (score 0):

SAS `proc sql` doesn't support window functions.  I find the re-merging aggregations to be a bit difficult to use, except in the obvious cases.  So, use a subquery or `join` and `group by`:

```
proc sql;
create table table5 as
   select t.rowid, t.YEAR, t.PERSONID, t.pidDifference, t.TIMETOEVENT, t.DAYSBETVISIT,
          tt.sum_DaysBetVisit
   from WORK.Table4_1 t left join
        (select personid, sum(DaysBetVisit) as sum_DaysBetVisit
         from WORK.Table4_1
         group by personid
         having min(pidDifference) = max(pidDifference) and min(pidDifference) = 0
        ) tt
        on tt.personid = t.personid;
```

Note:  This doesn't handle `NULL` values for `pidDifference`.  If that is a concern, you can add `count(pidDifference) = count(*)` to the `having` clause.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. I am testing your code. Running into some runtime errors. GIves some syntax errors. Will try to figure it out. Thank you for showing me a new way though.

Comment: @Mray . . . I had left in a line of the original code.